# MongoRestore is giving me the system cannot find the file

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to export my local mongodb data to an atlas cluster and i created a dump and now i am using the command,

```
mongorestore --host Cluster0-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-00-qwo7v.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-qwo7v.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-qwo7v.mongodb.net:27017 --ssl --username username --password <PASSWORD> --authenticationDatabase admin
```

to try to restore it but is giving me the system cannot find the file specified.
But if i type mongorestore then it works but it doesn't restore to the atlas cloud server whatever.
What am i doing wrong?

Edit: The path i have used is C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\dump\gfg and dump\gfg but it is still not working.

Comment: what export/dump are you restoring?

Comment: @Jawad all of the data in the dump folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Usage of MongoRestore.exe can be found here.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#usage-in-backup-strategy)

**Standalone MongoDB**

When you use mongorestore, you need to provide the location of the file/dump you need to restore

```
mongorestore --host=mongodb1.example.net --port=27017 --username=user --authenticationDatabase=admin /opt/backup/mongodump-2011-10-24
```

last portion of the command is missing that defines the location of the data that needs to be restored.

**ReplicaSet**

To Restore MongoDB on a Replica, You have to stop the mongod and replace the files for mongodb. [Please read here for restoring database on replica set.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/restore-replica-set-from-backup/)

For restore from standalone to replica,

```
mongorestore --host myReplSet/mongo0.example.com:27020,mongo1.example.com:27012 --db <dbname> <folder_location>
```

If this still does not work, check path and ensure its properly escaped (spaces in name) or quoted.

**Your code with quotes and path:**

```
mongorestore --host Cluster0-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-00-qwo7v.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-qwo7v.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-qwo7v.mongodb.net:27017 --ssl --username username --password <PASSWORD> --authenticationDatabase admin "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\dump\gfg"
```

Comment: I put the directory dump/gfg but it is still giving the system cannot find the specified file

Comment: have you used the full path ?

Comment: yes I used C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\dump\gfg and dump\gfg but it ain't working

Comment: can you update your question with the path defined as well ?

Comment: Updated it just now

Comment: @SyedTalhaAli See my update for restoring to a replica set.